# Building Output from Source

Tags: build, delphi-7

I've been fiddling around with delphi 7 (yeah, outdated but free and working fine).
I've come to the point where I need to make a 'builder' that will build another file from source with custom settings such as 'application name' being a variable that can be changed.

I've made a builder that utilizes the DCC32.EXE and tried to redistribute this, its not been successful (Even with the entire bin folder/etc).

I'm wondering if hexediting or something else is needed (really not sure how to do this either!).

I'd love a few ideas on how to create an actual builder that can change settings in an app.

**EDIT**

Decided to do it with RT_RCDATA resources. It'll have to do :/

Comment: It is very unclear what you are actually asking for.  But dcc32.exe is not a redistributable program.

Comment: Ok, lets say I have a 'builder' which builds apps inside the application (such as changing a string in another app and copying/moving it to a location). Much like C#'s CodeDom. Just asking if its possible and how to go about it.

Comment: I am not familiar with CodeDom.  Please provide a use case example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: C# Codedom allows a user to completely compile an application from C# code within the application (Build within an application another application). I simply want to compile an application within another application with certain strings in the output changed.

Comment: Delphi has no such built-in capability, and as I said dcc32.exe is not redistributable.  So unless your builder app is run only on the same machine as the IDE (in which case, you can use `CreateProcess()` to invoke dcc32.exe aas needed), you will have to find another solution to your problem. You still have not explained what exactly you are trying to compile and change, or provide an example like I asked for.

Comment: Example: An EXE needs a new message box message changed from 'abc' to 'def'. A builder is used to achieve this through editing of the source and recompiling. I've looked around, resources is apparently the best way to do it.

Comment: The *correct* way to address that is to have the target application store the message text in a resource, then extract that resource at runtime when displaying the MessageBox.  The *builder* can then use [`UpdateResource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049(v=vs.85).aspx) to modify the text as needed, it does not need to remake the entire EXE. This also allows the text to be localized for multiple languages if the target EXE is to be used by international users.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, added a resource and called it in the application when needed. Thanks for the help :)